# Health Insurance for ex-pats

Tags: italy, insurance, health

Am I covered by G.H.I. Blue Cross/Blue Shield if I move to Italy under an elective residency visa?

Comment: Have you tried asking the customer service department at Blue Cross/Blue shield?  It probably depends on how long you plan to stay in Italy.  If you abandon your US residence, I suspect you'll no longer be eligible for BC/BS coverage.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to check with your provider to make sure that your plan has full coverage for you abroad. Insurers do offer plans for expats, and, if yours does not, you can try searching on 'global health insurance' for other that do. As examples:

- [Aetna](https://www.aetna.com/individuals-families/international-insurance.html)
- [IMG](https://www.imglobal.com/international-health-insurance/global-medical-insurance)
- [Cigna](https://www.cignaglobal.com/)
- [Allianz](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/apply/expat-plan/)
- [GeoBlue Global Medical](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/geo-blue/xplorer/)

Also returned in the Google search is this article on [researching international health insurance companies.](https://www.internationalinsurance.com/health/best-companies.php)

Answer (score 0):

BCBS plans may provide some emergency coverage if you get injured or sick. I agree - you should check with your plan provider. A travel insurance plan is a better option for short term travel (less than one year). Expat plans, or International Health Insurance, are more comprehensive plans and make sense for people living abroad - like expats.